# Unable to create table in Hbase

Tags: hbase, access-control

I'm trying to create table in Hbase namespace using below command, but getting permission problem.

```
hbase(main):010:0> create 'hbasetest:my_table', 'fam'

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient permissions for user 'qjdht' (global, action=CREATE)
```

I gave permisions to user 'qjdht'.

```
hbase(main):003:0> grant '@hbasetest', 'RWXCA', '@hbasetest'

0 row(s) in 0.8160 seconds
```

user qjdht is member of group hbasetest, still I'm getting same permission problem.

Comment: try and check -  user_permission 'tablename'

Comment: I'm unable to create table..how ill check user_permission 'tablename' ?

Answer (score 0):

In shell, you can issue the command **user_permission 'tablename'**. But since you are not able to create it at the first place, you cannot use that.

Try this **create 'my_table', 'fam'**. The username would be taken anyways I suppose. Once you grant the permission, and create the table, Hbase should take care of permission and allow you to perform operations

If still issue occurs, super user should grant permission. So may be when you grant permission, it is not taking it. You can ask your admin to grant access

Hope one of the steps would work. Please post results

Comment: Admin has granted me permissions but its not working on namespace  level...also in Error above it shows global scope whereas I'm creating table in namespace ..if you can suggest something on it ?

Comment: so are you still getting the same error as in question? A similar error reference is [here](https://support.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/201998166-HBase-SQL-statement-fails-with-Insufficient-permissions-for-user). See of any of the thing is matching based on your use case. The [documentation](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hbase.accesscontrol.configuration) has even more information in general. While granting permission, in your question, i see that you r granting for groupname hbasetest and for namespace hbasetest, as last thing in grant is namespace. I hope u might take a look there

Comment: admin granted me grant 'username','RWXCA' this worked why namespace level granting not working?

Comment: good. The namespace you are giving is again, hbasetest. But you need to give a correct namespace there. I Hope the solution worked. Can you please accept the solution. Thank you

Comment: It's not working..I'm looking for namespace level grants..namespace names are correct

Comment: Hope you have seen this                                                        **Namespace Admins** - a namespace admin with Create permissions can create or drop tables within that namespace, and take and restore snapshots. A namespace admin with Admin permissions can perform operations such as splits or major compactions on tables within that namespace. And the following too from the documentation link given earlier Namespace:

**hbase> grant 'service', 'RWXCA', '@test-NS'**

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of you hbase? You might be interested in below link

https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HBASE-12098

This was a know issue and it is available in 0.98.7+ release.

Hope this information is helpful for you.